# From Keyword Not Found Where Expected Error in Self Join

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a data table Employees, I want to show the employee name, the employee number, the manager number and the manager name of the employee who has the least salary in the company. I decide to perform a self join, and here's my code:

```
select worker.employee_id, worker.last_name "Worker Last Name",
worker.salary manager.last_name "Manager Last Name", manager.manager_id
from employees worker join employees manager
on worker.manager_id = manager.employee_id
having worker.salary = (select min(salary)
                        from employees);
```

However, when I run this, the error "from keyword not found where expected" pops up. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, realized my own mistakes. I forgot to place a comma between worker.salary and manager.last_name, and I should not have WHERE instead of HAVING.

```
select worker.employee_id, worker.last_name "Worker Last Name",
worker.salary, manager.last_name "Manager Last Name", manager.manager_id
from employees worker join employees manager
on worker.manager_id = manager.employee_id
where worker.salary = (select min(salary)
                       from employees);
```

After fixing those two mistakes, the code runs fine.